# How to check the version number of Eigen C++ template library?

Tags: c++, eigen

I added several different versions of Eigen to default including directory of Visual C++.
But I got collapse problem when using `LDLT` (Cholesky decomposition) for some of the testing numerical examples.

So I want to determine which version is actually active when debugging the code.

Is there any function which can indicate the current active Eigen version number?

Comment: At compile-time you have `EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION`, `EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION` and `EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION`, you can easily embed this information in your application.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, if they are `3`, `1` and `91` respectively, does this mean the most latest `3.20` since there is no `3.191` release?

Comment: 3.1.91 sounds like a beta version of 3.2 to me, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: It is not the desired 3.2.0 release. The version number macros are defined in `Macros.h` located at ``\Eigen\src\Core\util\``. thank you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This answer is only a summary from the comments above:

- At compile-time you have `EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION`, `EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION`
  and `EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION`, you can easily embed this information in
  your application.
- `3.1.91` sounds like a `beta version` of `3.2`.
- The version number macros are defined in `Macros.h` located at
  `\Eigen\src\Core\util\`.

Comment: On Debian or similar: `cat /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h | grep VERSION` will show you the version.

Answer (score 21):

In order to check the version number of Eigen C++ template library, just type

```
dpkg -p libeigen3-dev
```

in the terminal.
Or just type

```
pkg-config --modversion eigen3
```

you will get the Eigen version.

Comment: Kinda funny, first command gives "3.2.0-8" and second one "3.2.92".

Answer (score 5):

On Linux:

```
grep "#define EIGEN_[^_]*_VERSION" /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h
```

You'll get something like:

```
#define EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION 3
#define EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION 3
#define EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION 7
```

It means version 3.3.7

Answer (score 4):

Although it is not the goal of the OP, people finding this question may be interested in checking if the version is equal to are newer than a specific release for compatibility reasons with different versions of Eigen. This can be done more easily using the `EIGEN_VERSION_AT_LEAST(x, y, z)` macro as follows:

```
#if EIGEN_VERSION_AT_LEAST(3,3,0)
    // Implementation for Eigen 3.3.0 and newer
#else
    // Implementation for older Eigen versions
#endif
```

This macro is also defined in `Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h` and uses `EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION`, `EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION` and `EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION` internally.